# Stats based on Access Token?

Tags: facebook, spam, facebook-access-token

My app stores the Facebook Access Token for offline use. The main purpose of the app is to allow users to automatically posts on the walls of people within a specified number of days of their friends birthday.

My app has been blocked by Facebook due to spam (some users are sending marketing messages to their friends instead of using the app for it's purpose).

I want to find out who those users are and block their access to my application. The only problem is that my Facebook App has a few hundred access tokens (one for each user of my application). The insights dashboard does not provide me with stats per access token. I need to find out which of my users are getting their wall posts reported as spam.

Is there any way of doing this?

After appealing, Facebook has unblocked my application but I don't want it to happen again. As far as I can tell, I can find out the number of people who have reported the wall posts as spam...but I don't know which access token made those posts...and hence don't know which of my users is posting spam messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Facebook job to keep track of your application *internal* activities. You should be logging every activity, at least posts ids returned when someone posts anything on their friends' wall.

And one more time... you **DON'T** need the `offline_access` permission to publish something when the user is *offline*!

Comment: For each post, I log the following: From Profile ID, To Profile ID, Message Text, Result, Post ID.


The problem with this is that I do not want to just log successful (or failed) posts. I need to know which users removed the post from their wall (or reported it as spam).

Comment: your best bet is adding a real developer contact email for users to report issues to. Also try analyzing the text (if your policy allow this) and try to find spammy senders

Comment: All the messages are "happy birthday" type of messages. I had a look and couldn't find any real spammy messages. At the end of the day, it is hard to stop people from removing posts from their wall...I need a report which shows me which of my users are getting the most spam reports so i can take action.